# What is a JVM instruction?

Tags: java, jvm

So I was talking to somebody who runs Interviews (your standard HR manager) about what they really look for in an interview, and he mentioned something (among many other things) about testing for JVM Instruction knowledge.

I didn't know what those were, but I thought he was talking about bytecode instructions.

I have done some research and it seems that I can't find anything on "JVM Instructions", all I find are references to bytecode instructions, which I already knew about.

For example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html at first seems to talk about JVM Instructions, but that seems to be what I know of as bytecode instructions.

So my question is, are there such thing as JVM Instructions that are separate from bytecode instructions, or are they one and the same?

Thanks

Comment: JVM instructions are what the byte code consists of. Interesting thing to ask at an interview though, are they expecting their applicants to write their own compiler?

Comment: As far as I know they are one in the same.  And I have no idea why an interviewer would test for this knowledge.  It has little to no practical use in terms of Java coding.  Really it's only useful if you're going to be writing/maintaining a Java/Groovy/JVM-based compiler.

Comment: What does your software do that a knowledge of bytecode instructions matters?  I don't mean to imply that such knowledge isn't necessary, only that I myself am naive to such things for the most part.

Comment: How inane of him. Congrats to you for honestly exploring and asking the community to find out if you really understand the question or not.  That would be enough to get you hired in my shop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So my question is, are there such thing as JVM Instructions that are separate from bytecode instructions, or they one and the same?

They are one and the same.

Comment: Aside: I do not see the point of asking questions to determine if a Java candidate has in-depth knowledge of bytecodes.  Even in the few situations where you do need know that kind of thing, you wouldn't need that kind of knowledge in your head.  There *is* a point to high-level knowledge of what bytecodes are, how they are produced and how they are executed, but that's a different set of interview questions.

Answer (score 4):

He's most likely just talking about bytecode instructions, as that's what the JVM runs.

Answer (score 0):

All i know is that ByteCode is an abstract machine language that is executed by JVM. Some of the instructions that make bytecode are **dadd**(add two numbers), **ddiv**(divide two numbers), **dload**, etc. They fall into certain groups type conversion, arithmetic and logic, etc. So i guess they are ***same***. These instructions make up a java byte code. List of bytecode instructions http://www.stackframe.com/documents/bytecode.html